# Not able to add property to object in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to add a property 'sum' to my object while accessing the object using reduce but new property is not getting added when I am doing in react native although when I tried the same thing in jsfiddle it worked fine.

I am thinking if it has to done in a different way in react native.

I tried the same thing in jsfiddle and it worked fine.

```
const filtered = Object.keys(raw)
    .filter(key => {
      if (key.includes(cat)) {
        return true;
      }
      if (cat == "all") {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    })
.reduce((obj, key) => {
      obj[key] = raw[key];
      obj[key].sum = 20;
      return obj;
    }, {});
```

Sum property is not getting added in my object in reactnative.

Comment: What is the value of `raw[key]`? If it some primitive value, like a string or a number, those are immutable types, you wont be able to add properties to them. Make sure your value is an object, log it or log `typeof(raw[key])` to see if it is in fact a primitive.

Comment: raw[key] return a object `{ 'fruit': [{'type': 'regional'}, {'type': 'imported' }] }`

Comment: Hi @mac, can you please provide the values of the object `raw` and the value of `cat`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
    obj[key] = {
          ...raw[key],
          sum: 20
    }
```